# How to add a logged in user to a Joomla 2.5 user group?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

When one of our "Registered" users places an order, we have a plugin that successfully adds them to another User Group called "Customer".  This works very nicely in the flow of things using `JUserHelper::addUserToGroup()`.

The problem is that even though the user record IS correctly updated, they're already logged in, so they are forced to log out and back in to have the necessary ACL that they need.

I've hunted through all the jUser code and docs, and cannot find a way to alter the currently logged in user that is yielded by `$user =& JFactory::getUser();`.

I expect the answer may be obvious to someone who understands the Joomla MVC better than I, but my head is reeling with all the code I've read trying to find a way to accomplish this.

**UPDATE:**

Lodder's answer below technically works, but while the "User Groups" ARE actually being updated, the AuthGroups and AuthLevels are not.  After my code is run, the $user object DOES show the groups there in, but further down in the object,

```
        [_authGroups:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
            )

        [_authLevels:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 2
            )
```

There appears to be no way to change this in the current session because it's all protected, and the only place it's updated is in user.php at `$identities = $this->getAuthorisedGroups();`, which only executes on the first time it's encountered.

Comment: Have just done a little research on this and there is a way to do it, however it's rather hard I think as the usergroup the user belong to is is in the session, hence why they need to log back in. I'll have a look around and let you know as I too would actually like to find this out. +1 for the good question

Comment: I was just looking at calling the logout and login functions but it appears it will fire all/any events associated with doing that - not sure what that really means at the moment, but....

Comment: It's basically a known issue. The session data is very hard to change given that users maybe logged in multiple times and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this but I'm not 100% sure if it will work in your situation. Best give it a try:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->id == $user['id']){
   $session = JFactory::getSession();
   $session->set('user', new JUser($user->id));
}
```

It has been known to work for a few people.

Let me know if it works and if not, I'll see what else I can find.

Comment: Thank you good sir....I'm in the midst of tinkering now, so will see how well this works or not.

Comment: Updated the question with the downside of this answer...it technically work, but the active ACL info does not reflect the new group(s), and there does not appear to be a way to alter that.